# Undesired spaces in \newenvironment break commands

Tags: table-of-contents, environments, appendices

I created a new environment to change the behavior of the toc for appendices. The commands work fine when using them outside `\newenvironment`, but not within `\newenvironment`.

The root cause seems the line `\addtocontents{toc}{\let\protect\l@chapter\protect\l@section}`: Outside the environment, the corresponding line in MWE.toc is `\let \l@chapter \l@section` while the same command within the new environment leads to the toc line `\let \l @chapter\l @section` (please notice the spaces before the `@` symbols).

How can I get rid of the space before the @ sign?

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook} 
\usepackage{appendix}

\newenvironment{myappendices}{
\makeatletter
\addappheadtotoc
\addtocontents{toc}{\begingroup}
\addtocontents{toc}{\let\protect\l@chapter\protect\l@section}
\makeatother}{
\addtocontents{toc}{\endgroup}
}

\flushbottom
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{One}
\chapter{Two}

\appendix

% version without \newenvironment: works
\makeatletter
\addappheadtotoc
\addtocontents{toc}{\begingroup}
\addtocontents{toc}{\let\protect\l@chapter\protect\l@section}
\makeatother
\chapter{Appendix One}
\chapter{Appendix Two}
\addtocontents{toc}{\endgroup}

% version with \newenvironment: broken toc
\begin{myappendices}
\chapter{Appendix Three}
\chapter{Appendix Four}
\end{myappendices}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` should be *around* the `\newenvironment`, not inside it.

Comment: move `\makeatletter`  and `\makeatother` outside the environment definition, they do nothing inside the definition, also protect the ends of lines in the definition with `%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Although the solution didn't come from me (credits goes to egreg and David Carlisle in the comments of the question), I'll post a proper answer to this question.*

Moving `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` outside the environment solved the issue indeed:

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{myappendices}{%
  \addappheadtotoc%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\begingroup}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\let\protect\l@chapter\protect\l@section}%
}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\endgroup}%
}%
\makeatother
```

[image]

Below the full MWE (now working):

```
\documentclass{scrbook} 
\usepackage{appendix}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{myappendices}{%
  \addappheadtotoc%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\begingroup}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\let\protect\l@chapter\protect\l@section}%
}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\endgroup}%
}%
\makeatother

\flushbottom
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{One}
\chapter{Two}

\appendix

% version without \newenvironment: works
\makeatletter
\addappheadtotoc
\addtocontents{toc}{\begingroup}
\addtocontents{toc}{\let\protect\l@chapter\protect\l@section}
\makeatother
\chapter{Appendix One}
\chapter{Appendix Two}
\addtocontents{toc}{\endgroup}

% version with \newenvironment: works now, too
\begin{myappendices}
\chapter{Appendix Three}
\chapter{Appendix Four}
\end{myappendices}
\end{document}
```